# About a property of the upper triangular projection of a matrix

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, analysis

I need a hand checking that a property about the upper triangle projection of an infinite matrix holds.

$\bullet$ Let A be an infinite matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{i\geq 1\;j\geq 1}$. We define its upper triangular projection as follows:

$$P_T(A)=\left\lbrace
  \begin{array}{l}
     a_{i,j},\;\text{ if }i\leq j \\
     0,\;\text{ otherwise.} \\
  \end{array}
  \right.$$

Then, the property i'm interested in is the following. If we denote as $I$ the usual identity matrix, and we consider $A\in B(\ell^2)$ (the space of bounded and linear operators from $\ell^2$ to $\ell^2$), then:

$$\lVert I-P_T(A)\rVert_{B(\ell^2)}\leq\lVert A\rVert_{B(\ell^2)}.$$

Thanks a lot for any advice you can give me about the proof of this fact!

EDIT: The matrix A involved in the proof I'm reading is the following

$$A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 &\frac{1}{5} & \cdots \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &\frac{1}{3} & \ddots\\
\frac{-1}{3} & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \ddots \\
\frac{-1}{5} & 0 & \frac{-1}{3} & 0 & -1 & 0 & \ddots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\ \end{array} \right)$$

Comment: You can, e.g., by scaling, make $A$ arbitrarily "small" compared to $I$ so that the left-hand side would be close to one while the right-hand side would be arbitrarily small.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pavel. Would that mean that the property is false?
I found it in a step of a proof I'm studying. I suspect maybe the author meant $(I-P_T)(B)$ instead of $I- P_T(B)$...

Comment: You can think even about more trivial case where $A=0$. If one would take $I-P_T$ (that is, the strict lower triangular part: $(I-P_T)A$ is the strict lower triangular part of $A$) then it depends on what $\|\cdot\|_{B(\ell^2)}$ stands for exactly.

Comment: If it is the spectral norm (the operator norm induced by the $\ell^2$-norm), it does not need to be true in general. Consider, e.g., $A=\pmatrix{1&1&2\\-2&-2&1\\2&-2&0}$. Its 2-norm is about 3.1623, while the 2-norm of its strict lower triangular part is about 3.2361. Maybe there are more assumptions on $A$?

Comment: I edited the OP with the matrix A involved in the proof. Also, the norm I'm using is the defined as: $\lVert A\rVert_{B(\ell^2)}=\sup_{\lVert x\rVert=1}\lVert{Ax}\rVert$ ($x\in\ell^2$)

Comment: In the proof, one of the parts is seeing that A does not belong to $B(\ell^2)$. In order to see this, the author states that $\infty=\lVert{I-P_T(A)}\rVert\leq \lVert{A}\rVert$.
I already saw that $\infty=\lVert{I-P_T(A)}\rVert$. The inequality that remains is my doubt, I'm not sure if it is a general property or only something specific for this matrix...